# Difference - Font and Typeface

Tags: website-design, design, web, font, typography

I would like to know the difference between a font and a typeface. If anyone could please help me.

I tried to Google it, but I can't understand that in general, Why the term 'Fonts' is used rather than 'TypeFaces'?

Comment: [Similar question on the Graphic Design site, on the practical difference between the terms](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12717/does-the-difference-between-a-font-and-a-typeface-subside)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the best explanation I have found was in this article which explains how fonts constitute a typeface. To quote the [article](http://nerdplusart.com/type-terminology-smackdown/)

> A typeface is a family of fonts (very often by the same designer).
>   Within a typeface there will be fonts of varying weights or other
>   variations. E.g., light, bold, semi-bold, condensed, italic, etc. Each
>   such variation is a different font. The only evolution in terminology
>   that results from the transition from metal-cast to digital fonts is
>   that (point) size is no longer fixed.

From a historical perspective of how the word font came about, You should check out [this excellent article which explains the difference between the two and also talks about the history of the word font](http://mindgruve.com/blog/2013/05/typeface-vs-font-whats-the-difference-2/). To quote the article

> Around the fifteenth century, when printers hand-set type, they had to
>   pull actual metal letters, numbers, and symbols out of a giant box.
>
> [image]
>
> This collection of characters was called a “font.”

With regards to typefaces

> Typefaces describe the overall look of the characters contained within
>   the font. If you see in Fig. 2, you’ll see a font of News Gothic –
>   News Gothic is the typeface.
>
> [image]

Also to quote [this article on Nextweb](http://thenextweb.com/dd/2012/05/20/is-it-a-font-or-a-typeface/#!BhLJm)

> “the physical embodiment of a collection of letters, numbers, symbols,
>   etc. (whether it’s a case of metal pieces or a computer file) is a
>   font. When referring to the design of the collection (the way it
>   looks) you call it a typeface.”

Lastly these definitions from Adobe can help explain it further

> **typeface** The letters, numbers, and symbols that make up a design of type. A typeface is often part of a type family of coordinated
>   designs. The individual typefaces are named after the family and are
>   also specified with a designation, such as italic, bold or condensed.
>
> **Font**
>
> One weight, width, and style of a typeface. Before scalable type,
>   there was little distinction between the terms font, face, and family.
>   Font and face still tend to be used interchangeably, although the term
>   face is usually more correct.

Comment: You mean to say that font is the size and style of a typeface.!? And a typeface consist of two or more fonts with glyph specified in that font!?

Comment: So a file that contains descrioption of how each symbol should be visually represented is a Font, and a Typeface is the general concept of that visual representation?

Comment: A typeface is the aesthetics and design of lettering. A font is the physical thing you use or install. ["Typeface" is to "font" as "song" is to "track" or "MP3"](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/12719/3327). Your handwriting is a typeface without a font. Wingdings and [Chartwell](https://www.scribbletone.com/typefaces/ff-chartwell) are fonts without a typeface.

Answer (score 13):

A typeface is a distinct design of glyphs, a font is a specific variant therof, consisting of a full set of glyphs.

Helvetica is a typeface, as is Courier. They are different typefaces, and by definition different fonts.

Helvetica condensed bold is a font, as is Helvetica italic. They both belong to the Helvetica typeface, but they are different fonts.

Comment: Nice and short answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is a clear distinction:

Helvetica is a type family.
Helvetica Bold is a typeface.
12pt Helvetica Bold is a font.

I remember the definition this way: Family > Face > Font

Comment: That was true in the days when type was a physical object. But in the digital world, your second example is both a typeface and a font. In other words, it's not so clear.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a clear difference. There is no hard-and-fast definitions of the two.

As other's have pointed out, common usage is that the font is specific to a set of actual letters (be it physical or digital) and typeface is the overall design (that would usually be applied to a number of fonts as a family).

A physical example would be: Futura Bold 12pt lead type.

A digital example would be: Futura-Bold.ttf

But in common usage, was also use 'font' interchangeably with 'typeface'. "Which font are you using? Helvetica?"

Comment: I agree with your point of the terms being used interchangeabley in vernacular, but in typography jargon, there *is* a difference.

Comment: @Bakabaka but it's not absolutely clear. There is no typographic definition set in stone for these terms. In fact, a lot of typographic terms are loosely defined. Historically, we could perhaps be more clear (font = one purchasable set of physical letters at a certain size) but the digital world has blurred things quite a bit.

Comment: An example would be open type. You can now have one opentype *font* that also happens to contain a complete *typeface* family (albeit a smaller family).